# SharePoint 2013 Workflow approving "Start a task process"

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, tasks

What I have noticed is that whenever the workflow assigns a task to someone specifically, still any other random user is able to Edit/Fill data from task form. And even any user is able to approve the task not assigned to him. Though this wasn't the case in 2010 workflows. Any idea why this strange behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the task process and there you can find the option under settings "Only allow task recipients and process owners to read and edit workflow tasks"

Comment: Where in SharePoint designer?

Comment: Yes, Check the Task edit section

Comment: Well I am still unable to find it, if possible could you please add the screenshot?

Comment: I have tried this as well, but that doesn't works even.

Comment: 2010 workflow having the simple option to restrict other users but 2013 doesn't. Tried the below URL hope it will resolve your problem   http://zsvipullo.blogspot.in/2015/03/set-right-permission-to-sharepoint.html

Comment: But this is not in English unfortunately.

Comment: You can use google translator to see the content

Answer (score 0):

[image: Screenshot]

Please find the screenshot as a reference and let me know if you face any other problem

Comment: This is in context to 2010 workflow tasks, well Palani I am looking for 2013 workflows.

Comment: Sorry, try to uncheck the "Assign a task to each member within group"

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Attached the screenshot for  "Assign a task to each member within group" options